# jar file to web service

Tags: java, url, service, jar, web

I have coded a project and later built it to a jar file. Until here everything works perfectly. Jar file gives appropriate outputs.

But my jar file has to be in the server. I have uploaded it to server and with console, I could make it run. My question is, I have to prepare such a web service url that another user can connect, and when he connects, my jar file has to run and give outputs. basically I am trying to convert it to a web service.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about jetty? try using that. it is easy to implement web services using that from a POJO.

Answer (score 0):

You can build very simple web service  to expose the functionality in the jar file- JaxWS provides extensive APIs for creating and deploying service in to any web server container. Here is very simple tutorial which guide you

[http://www.benmccann.com/blog/web-services-tutorial-with-apache-cxf/](http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/web-services-tutorial-with-apache-cxf/)

Cheers 
Satheesh